# Set UserAuth delete cascade without adding dependency to ServiceModel

Tags: servicestack

There are some entities that I want to ensure are deleted if a user is deleted so I have set their models like so to be used with OrmLite:

```
public class UserProcess
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(UserAuth), OnDelete = "CASCADE")]
    public string UserAuthId { get; set; }
    // ... Other properties
}
```

This works but it requires me to add the ServiceStack nuget package to the ServiceModel project as `UserAuth` is not defined in the `ServiceStack.Interfaces` package.

I prefer not to add dependencies to class library.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either add the attribute dynamically on Startup, e.g:

```
typeof(UserProcess)
     .AddAttributes(new ForeignKeyAttribute {...});
```

Or create the Foreign Key after the table is created, either manually or you can use the [[PostCreateTable] attribute to execute custom SQL](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/README.md#pre--post-custom-sql-hooks-when-creating-and-dropping-tables) after the table is created.

The alternative is to create a separate DTO without any dependencies and use [AutoMapping Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping) to copy the properties over.